# OpenCV imwrite is not working

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a simple OpenCV application that takes a video stream from the webcam, and when the `spacebar` is pressed it captures the current image and freezes on that image. When I try to use the `cv::imwrite()` method to save the picture to disk, it does not work. The code successfully compiles but it does not save the image. It is returning a false value as well from the call. I am not sure if this is an issue of type of image or something else, but I seem to be stumped.

Here is the code for my current cpp class:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat picture;
char key;

class FacialRec {

};

int main() {
    //Starting the video
    VideoCapture videoCapture(0);

    if (!videoCapture.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Unable to open video file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    namedWindow("Webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while(true) {
        Mat frame;
        videoCapture.retrieve(frame);
        bool success = videoCapture.read(frame);

        if (!success) {
            cout << "Could not read from video file" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        imshow("Webcam", frame);
        key = waitKey(30);

        if (key == 27) { //escape key pressed: stop program
            cout << "ESC pressed. Program closing..." << endl;
            break;
        }else if (key == ' ') { //spacebar pressed: take a picture
            picture = frame;
            key = -1;

            while (true) {
                imshow("Webcam", picture);

                key = waitKey(30);

                if (key == 27 || key == 32) {
                    cout << "ESC or SPACE pressed. Returning to video..." << endl;
                    break;
                }

                if (key == 115) {
                    //trying to save to current directory
                    bool maybe = imwrite("/testimage.jpg", picture);
                    // maybe bool is always getting value of 0, or false
                   cout << "s was pressed. saving image " << maybe << endl;
                }   
            }
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to write `testimage.jpg` to the `/` directory. The executing program probably doesn't have sufficient permissions to write to that directory. Based on your comment, you probably want

```
//trying to save to current directory
bool maybe = imwrite("./testimage.jpg", picture);
```

Since `.` denotes the current working directory.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't completely sure about how to do the directory. This solved it.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV sometimes has problems to write to a `.jpg` image. Try to change that to `.png` or `.bmp` to see if that makes a difference in your case.

If you have further issues with writing images, you can debug them in `OpenCV` by adding this few lines of code to display them and see if they are valid:

```
// Create a window for display.
namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

// Show our image inside it.
imshow( "Display window", picture );                   

// Wait for a keystroke in the window
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: assigning it to a bool still calls the function...this would make no difference. In fact, it is good, as it keeps a record of success!

Comment: It seems the directory was the issue, thanks for helping with displaying it as well. Fixed a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions.

1. try a different file format.
2. does your IDE defiantly know your target folder / home path directory?
3. Is your image definitely valid? does it show when you imshow()?