# OpenCV imwrite not writing image

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying to write an image to a folder using OpenCV imwrite function.
The code compiles and runs successfully but the image is not saving in the folder/path.I am getting output from 'imshow' and my image is in CV_8UC1 format.

find the code below

```
    Mat reflection = function which computes image
    imshow("output image", reflection);
    imwrite("E:/New folder/img.bmp", reflection);
```

so I checked [current folder writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355291/opencv-imwrite-is-not-working) and modified code like this

```
bool check = imwrite("./img.bmp", reflection);
```

this 'bool *check*' status is 'false' and not writing the image.

I've also checked folder permission with guidelines from [microsoft help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754344(v=ws.11).aspx) my "E/New Folder/" is permitted to write. still, the image is not saving.
I am okay with any image format .jpg, .png and .bmp.
I am using windows 7, OpenCV 3.0, visual studio 2017.

Please help me and thanks for reading it

Comment: Have you tried without the path? Saving into current working dir or something... like imwrite("img.bmp", reflection); ?

Comment: Have you tried to convert the image to CV_8UC3?  I doubt 1-channel image can be stored in bmp file.

Comment: does it work if you choose `imwrite("E:/New folder/img.png", reflection);` instead?

Comment: are all the necessary dll's available to the application? For videowriter for example, no frames are written, if the opencv_ffmpeg dll is missing, but the program does run (and isn't complaining about a missing dll or something). Maybe there is some similar dependency for imwrite, too.

Comment: @Micka imwrite must has the -highugi flag for the linker, but it will throw a linker error if it is not available

Comment: @JamesDong I tried it still not working

Comment: @Micka I tried using .png & .jpg both did not work

Comment: @Kev1n91 afaik, in opencv 3 it is the imcodec lib or similar, not the highgui anymore. But I'm not completely sure since I typically use opencv 2.4.x

Comment: what happens if you simpy cout the matrix? Does it show valid values? Maybe your function produces some NaN Values?

Comment: @Kev1n91 values are good it's in range of 0-255

Comment: Do you cout it in your function or after you returned it? Sometimes the problem is, that the memory does not get copied into the new memory, and so it does not write out.

Answer (score 2):

Opencv doesn't seem to support saving BMP files check the [imwrite docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-alpha/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#bool%20imwrite(const%20String&%20filename,%20InputArray%20img,%20const%20vector%3Cint%3E&%20params)). Changing the filename to `img.png` should work. Also using `./` in windows is not valid, this is used in unix systems to represent the current working directory see [Windows current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32060632/4773139).
Updating it to

```
bool check = imwrite(".\img.png", reflection);
```

or

```
bool check = imwrite("img.png", reflection);
```

Should work

Comment: I tried it still not saving the image bool check value is false

Comment: It seems opencv cant save BMP files, change the file to "img.png"
[Docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-alpha/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html)

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV do support bmp, just use as follows.

`bool check = imwrite("img.bmp", reflection);`