# Opencv method imwrite don't work into ROS

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I'm using ROS Kinetic to subscribe to images topics, I'm using a .launcher to execute 2 instances of same node, this part is ok, but then I try to save these images inside the code of each node and don't have success. the cv::imageshow() works fine, but the imwrite don't write anywhere. I tried [these solutions ( both of them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355291/opencv-imwrite-is-not-working) and nothing.
Launcher code ( XML)

```
<launch>
  <node name="listenerRasp" pkg="image_receptor" type="imageReceptor"> 
    <remap from="/camera/image" to="/rasp/image/compressed"/>
    <param name="photoPath" type="string" value="/data/src/rasp" />
  </node>
<node name="listenerApp" pkg="image_receptor" type="imageReceptor" cwd="node">
    <param name="photoPath" type="string" value="/data/src/app" />
    <remap from="/camera/image" to="/app/image/compressed"/>
</node>

</launch>
```

and the cpp code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

static const std::string OPENCV_WINDOW = "Photo visualizer";

class ImageConverter
{
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
  image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;
  std::string topic_name;

//  image_transport::Publisher image_pub_;

public:
  ImageConverter()
: it_(nh_)
  {
    if( ros::param::has("/photoPath")){
        ros::param::get("/photoPath",topic_name);
    }
    // Subscribe to input video feed and publish output video feed
    image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/camera/image", 1, &ImageConverter::imageCb, this, image_transport::TransportHints("compressed"));
    //image_pub_ = it_.advertise("/image_converter/output_video", 1);

    cv::namedWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW);
  }

  ~ImageConverter()
  {
    cv::destroyWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW);
  }

  void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
  {
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;

    try
    {
      cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);

    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
      return;
    }

    // Draw an example circle on the video stream
//    if (cv_ptr->image.rows > 60 && cv_ptr->image.cols > 60)
  //    cv::circle(cv_ptr->image, cv::Point(50, 50), 10, CV_RGB(0,255,0));

    // Update GUI Window
    //ros::Time agora = ros::Time::now().toSec();
//  agora.toString();
    std::string nomePathFoto ="." + topic_name + "/2020testeAugust.jpeg";
  cv::imshow(OPENCV_WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
    cv::imwrite("2020testeAugust.jpg", cv_ptr->image);
  cv::waitKey(3);

    // Output modified video stream
    //image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "image_converter");
  ImageConverter ic;
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see the cpp code comes from [ROS tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) with few changes. Since it's more a OpenCV question than a ROS one, I decided to publish here

Comment: Just to eliminate the possibility of the image getting written, but to an unexpected location -- have you tried to write to an absolute path, eg `cv::imwrite("/tmp/2020testeAugust.jpg");` ?

Comment: idk how to explicit answer your comment but here it goes: yes, I've tried absolute `( "/data/src/2020testeAugust.jpg") ` , tried relative path in other ways: `("./2020testeAugust.jpg")` , `("2020testeAugust.jpg")` , `("/2020testeAugust.jpg")`.

Comment: And also I've tried change extensions: **2020testeAugust.jpg**, **2020testeAugust.png**, **2020testeAugust.bmp** and even without any extension, which gave an error, but that is expected cause the imWrite requires an extension.

Comment: @vasiliykarasev idk why but I just tried the specific folder you told me to, that worked, I suppose it's a permission problem or something like this. I'm trying using another folders, but why the `imwrite("/2020testeAugust.jpg")` don't work idk haha, anyway, trying to understand these things.. should I declare this problem solved?

Comment: You didnt convert ros image to opencv image in mat format

Comment: I'm sure if it's not C++ implementation issue, Python imwrite works fine.

Comment: Whats the return value of imwrite?

Comment: @VictoriaKepler problably the issue I was having ( now I made it work but only with absolute path, what's bad,  but still better than nothing haha) is because of my implementation, not the language. And I'm doing it in a Linux machine, which I'm not 100% used to. But thanks for help!

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I gonna check that! THanks for your help! ( To do this I simply clone the image to a cv::Mat object?